# Invalid record type error with Dataloader

Tags: managed-package, data-loader, record-type

I am getting an 'invalid record type' error when trying to update a record type for some contacts.

[image]

1. Currently, the contacts are of a a contact record type  created by an installed package. We are uninstalling the package, but before I do so I need to change the record types of these contacts.
2. I have created two new record types "Contact - New" and "Candidate - New". When created the new record types I selected that these were replacing the old types, and to update the records, but this apparently did not work.
3. I then exported the records matching the old record types.
4. I updated the CSV to replace the old record types with the new ones, and performed an update on the Contacts table.
5. I got 80-ish errors for the "Candidate - New" record type.
6. I tried exporting the RecordType table to get the full 18 digit ID, then tried re-updating but this did not work either and I received the same message.

All record types are active. All record types are currently using the contact page layout, which is not part of the installed package.

[image]

Can someone please help?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked to ensure that the profile you are using to update the Contacts has the Record Types you mention? Setup -> Profiles -> Record Types?

Comment: Oh my...that seemed to be the issue! At least, "Candidate - New" was not available to my sys admin profile. Thanks Cory!!

Comment: No problem. Happy Data Loading. :)

Comment: I have had a similar issue - the ownerId definitely had access to the recordTypeId. In the end, I was able to get around the issue by first creating the records under a different record type, then I updated the records to point to the actual correct record type, which worked. So, Insert operation kept failing with INSUFFICIENT ACCESS but the Update passed.